# How to remove certain characters on keyup

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'd like to dynamically replace all non-numeric input as the user types. I've got the input type set to `number`, but that still allows the user to type non-numbers, the browser just flags it.

Instead of just flagging non-numbers (for exampl, commas, spaces, or dashes), I'd like to simply remove them as the user types. The code listed here, which is very straightforward, is completely deleting the string if a non-number is encountered, which is not what I want.

```js
var cc = document.querySelector('input.credit-card-number');
cc.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
 this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
});
```

```html
<input type="number" class="credit-card-number">
```

### Edit

This is a Firefox-only problem. Chrome seems to work as expected. I'd still appreciate a fix if anyone can come up with one.

Comment: I'm wondering if this a Firefox bug...

Comment: is it compulsory to use the `number` type field ? and what about using a jquery solution which fixes it for firefox too

Comment: @JakeParis [not really a bug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Gecko_keypress_event), it's just the folks at Mozilla are very zealous when it comes to standards. That unfortunately isn't always the best approach. See my updated answer that works for Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Very frustrating when your problem title doesn't match your problem.  You want to remove non-numeric characters while typing, not certain.  I'm trying to find out how to remove specific chars and I keep only finding solutions like this that don't apply!

Comment: @MichaelFever This solution would work fine for you. Just change the regex to look for whichever characters you want to remove.

Comment: @JakeParis maybe, but my requirement is a bit different.  My field should only allow numbers (0-9), letters (a-z) and only these other chars: _ ( ) - as well as spaces.  I know how to do this by parsing the field but a regex solution would be so much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Sticking with `javascript` only, a slight modification will make this work. Change the input type from `number` to `text`.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input.credit-card-number');
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="text" class="form-control credit-card-number" placeholder="Ex: 0000 0000 0000 0000" />
```

2. Don't look like you want `jquery` solution but if you want to use one you can go for input masking for which there is a [library](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.inputmask) too and support various masking options like `Credit Card`, `IP Address` and `Mobile Numbers` you can see a demo for the credit card concerned section below I used `firefox` to create and test the demo.

```js
//Credit Card
$('.credit-card-number').inputmask('9999 9999 9999 9999', {
  placeholder: '____ ____ ____ ____'
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/css/inputmask.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="text" class="form-control credit-card-number" placeholder="Ex: 0000 0000 0000 0000" />
```

Comment: You're right: I don't want jquery. But your solution of changing the input type to regular `text` makes the javascript work as expected all browsers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

Firefox looks at `this.value` and says, "Ok, I'll just take the *whole value* of whatever is in the input and overwrite the *whole value*." Chrome somehow intuitively interprets keydown the way you intended, but Firefox literally follows your code truthfully. Unfortunately, that's not what you want, so you'll need to take a different approach with Firefox.

Instead of comparing strings, try comparing keystrokes a character at a time. **keyboardEvent.keycode** for Chrome and **keyboardEvent.which** for Firefox.
See **Demo 2**. BTW, keydown event is usually more reliable, if for some reason keyup is one off on results, keydown is probably better. If keydown needs 2 keystrokes to work, then try listening on capture phase instead of the bubble phase by setting the third parameter to `true`.

```
DOMObject.addEventListener('keydown', funk, true)
```

---

Change regex to:

```
/\D/gi
```

`\D` means anything that is not a digit and the `i` flag is for case insensitivity.

### Demo 1

```js
var cc = document.querySelector('input.credit-card-number');
cc.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/gi, '');
});
```

```html
<input type="number" class="credit-card-number">
```

### Demo 2

```
charCode > 47 && charCode < 58 ......0 to 9
charCode > 95 && charCode < 105......0 to 9 scroll locked 10-key pad
charCode == 8........................← Backspace
```

```js
var cc = document.querySelector('input.credit-card-number');

cc.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

  var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if ((charCode > 47 && charCode < 58) || (charCode > 95 && charCode < 105) || charCode == 8) {
    return true;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}, true);
```

```html
<input type="number" class="credit-card-number">
```

Comment: Your example 2 works great. The answer I've accepted is cleaner for my particular purposes, but thanks for your work here.

Comment: But actually, I believe the javascript the way I have it _should_ only replace the non-number with an empty string and return the modified string. Not completely erase the string if a non-number is found.

Comment: *"Not completely erase the string if a non-number is found."* Which was what Firefox was doing. The first paragraph is what was wrong the second paragraph is a solution. I submitted the update, because you were adamant on keeping `type='number'`, otherwise Demo 1 would work just as well on `type='text'` with a few chars less. If this answer helps at all you can still upvote it.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I appreciate that you appreciate it, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the input type from number to text.

edit:
At least in Mozilla Firefox it works. See here

https://jsfiddle.net/h9ap2ag8/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" class="credit-card-number">
</body>
</html>

var cc = document.querySelector('input.credit-card-number');
cc.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
});
```

Comment: It does for me. I don't understand why this got downvoted.

Comment: Because it allows input such as dashes, and commas. Also, changing the input type to text simply does _not_ solve the problem. That's why people downvoted it (I didn't myself).

Comment: Oh, somehow the regex got changed. I initially used your intial one. I updated it.